# How to override default keyboard navigation of Kendo UI List View

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to override the default keyboard navigation of the Kendo List View.

By default the Kendo keyboard navigation distinguishes between selected items and a current item. The keyboard navigation moves the current item separately from selected items. Selected items are highlighted and the current item has a border.

I would like the selected item to move with the current item.

I have tried disabling the Kendo keydown handler and replaced it with my own handler.

```
$('#listView').off('keydown.kendoListView');
$('#listView').on('keydown.kendoListView', function (e) {
    var listView = $('#listView').data('kendoListView');
    switch (e.which) {
        case 40:
            var newSelection = listView.select().next();
            listView.select(newSelection);
            listView.current(newSelection);
            break;
        case 38:
            var newSelection = listView.select().prev();
            listView.select(newSelection);
            listView.current(newSelection);
            break;
        }
});
```

This succeeds in the current and selected item matching each other but the scrolling doesn't line up. Pressing down appears to scroll the list view by more than one element. So the current item ends up being outside of the view.

An example of what I have tried is:
http://jsfiddle.net/blutter/ULLu8/19/

Is there a way to fix the scrolling? Or a better way to change the keyboard navigation of the Kendo Listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keydown handler needs to return false to prevent the extra scrolling.

So the handler is:

```
  $('#listView').on('keydown.kendoListView', function (e) {
      var listView = $('#listView').data('kendoListView');
      switch (e.which) {
          case 40:
              var newSelection = listView.select().next();
              listView.select(newSelection);
              listView.current(newSelection);
              break;
          case 38:
              var newSelection = listView.select().prev();
              listView.select(newSelection);
              listView.current(newSelection);
              break;
      }
      return false;
  });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/blutter/ULLu8/23/ for the working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

great solution.
you can enhance your code with listview `selectable: multiple`,
with more keyboard buttons click events - `HOME, END, PageDown, PageUp`,
and with auto scroll mode for long listviews.

```
var div = document.getElementById(lv1);   
var line_height = 26;
$('#lv1').off('keydown.kendoListView');
$('#lv1').on('keydown.kendoListView', function(e) {
    var listView = $('#lv1').data('kendoListView');
    switch (e.which) {
      case 33: //page up
        var newSelection = listView.select().index() > 10 ?
          listView.items()[listView.select().index() - 10] :
          listView.items()[0];
        if (listView.options.selectable == 'multiple')
          listView.clearSelection();

        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);

        div.scrollTop = 0;
        break;
      case 34: //page down
        var newSelection = listView.items().length - listView.select().index() > 10 ?
          listView.items()[listView.select().index() + 10] :
          listView.items()[listView.items().length - 1];
        if (listView.options.selectable == 'multiple')
          listView.clearSelection();

        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);

        div.scrollTop = listView.items().length * line_height;
        break;
      case 35: // END button
        listView.clearSelection();
        var newSelection = listView.items()[listView.items().length - 1];
        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);

        div.scrollTop = listView.items().length * line_height;
        break;
      case 36: // HOME button
        listView.clearSelection();
        var newSelection = listView.items()[0];
        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);

        div.scrollTop = 0;
        break;
      case 38: //arrow up
        var newSelection = listView.select().prev();
        if (listView.options.selectable == 'multiple')
          listView.clearSelection();
        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);
        break;
      case 40: // arrow down
        var newSelection = listView.select().next();
        if (listView.options.selectable == 'multiple')
          listView.clearSelection();
        listView.select(newSelection);
        listView.current(newSelection);
        break;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

check my example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/snir/ffan5v86/7/